# Turn string containing two words in two seperate strings in R

Tags: r, vector, split

Assume following simple character vector:

```
x <- c("Indiana Jones", "Tom Cruise", "Brad Pitt")
```

The goal is to split each string containing two words (so containing a space, basically). So in this case I want the vector to be like:

```
x <- c("Indiana", "Jones", "Tom", "Cruise", "Brad", "Pitt")
```

Is there perhaps a specific package which may help me to do this?

Comment: How about `unlist(strsplit(x, " "))`?

Comment: That works! Many thanks!

Comment: Or `scan(text = x, what = "")`.

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be Harrison Ford?

Comment: or use the `word` command in `stringr`